# Swift Combine: How to specify the Error type of tryMap(_:)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, combine

In the Combine framework, we can throw a generic `Error` protocol type while using `tryMap`.

However, how can we be more specific about the `Error` type?

For example,

```swift
let publisher = urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request).tryMap { (data, response) -> (Data, HTTPURLResponse) in
      guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        throw URLError(.cannotParseResponse)
      }
      return (data, response)
}
```

How to specify the `Error` type of this `publisher`? I'd like to use `URLError` instead of `Error`.

I found the method `setFailureType(to:)` in the `Combine` framework. However, it is not available to `tryMap(_:)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`setFailureType(to:)` is only to force the failure type of a publisher with failure type `Never`. `tryMap` always uses `Error` as the error type because any `Error` could be thrown in the closure body, so you need to use `mapError` to force the `URLError` type:

```
let map_error = publisher.mapError({ error -> URLError in
    switch (error) {
    case let url_error as URLError:
        return url_error
    default:
        return URLError(.unknown)
    }
})
```

Comment: Great explanation, but why `error.self` here rather than just `error`? Purely style, but this might be more straightforward as `mapError { $0 as? URLError ?? URLError(.unknown) }`.

Comment: Good catch, I had a previous solution up where the switch was checking the type instead of using `case let`, and that did require `error.self`. Made the change and forgot to change that. And yeah, if you're just checking for the one type, your form would be more concise.

Answer (score 4):

You can also accomplish this with `flatMap`. This will allow you to specify both the `Output` and `Error` type at once, like so:

```
struct SomeResponseType {
    let data: Data
    let response: HTTPURLResponse
}

let publisher = urlSession.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .flatMap { (data, response) -> AnyPublisher<SomeResponseType, URLError > in
      guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        return Fail(error: URLError(.cannotParseResponse))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      return Just(SomeResponseType(data: data, response: response)
          .setFailureType(to: URLError)
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```